# react-query dynamic number of parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I will have product filter on ecommerce page. I'm not sure how can I pass dynamic number of parameters in my query? Because sometimes will query use 1 parameter sometimes 6 and more.

Example

```
const fetchProducts = async (size, color, weight, deep,) => {
  const parsed = await ky(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/products/get?size=${size}&color=${color}`
  ).json();

  return parsed;
}; 


  const { data, status } = useQuery([size, color,], () => fetchPosts(size, color));
```

Sometimes will be 10 different parameters from the product filter, sometimes just 1...

How can I handle this dynamically? I will need then put the filter on prisma backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `qs` package to handle all params.

Example:

```
const fetchProducts = (params)=>{
 const query = qs.stringify(params);
 const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/products/get?";
 const parsed = await ky(baseUrl + query);
....
}

const params = {color:"red", size:"big"}
const query = qs.stringify(params);
//output: "color=red&size=big"
```

Comment: Thanks its work, but i cant destruct the query on next.js backend :-( i getting undefined or { 'queryKey[0][name]': 'Samsung' } on console.log(req.query) . Have you any tips how destruct this?

Comment: @Radas Can you please add the backend code to your question as well? Or maybe consider creating a new question as it may fall outside the scope of the original problem (which this answer seemed to have solved).